# ListView setOnItemClickListener Does Not Trigger

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, onitemclicklistener

click listener not working when I click an item.

in this program first two arraylist updated  using update(). then this list view are sent to other class to make list view. but clicking each item doesn't toast anything.

```
public class BlockActivity extends Activity {
ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> contactnumber= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contactname= new ArrayList<String>();
public static SQLiteDatabase database;
SQLiteDatabase myDB= null;
CustomAdapter adapter;

ArrayList<String> contactnum= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> contactnam= new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button pickContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);






    update();



    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, contactnam, contactnum);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);


  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) 
      {

           /*new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
              .setMessage("Something here")
              .setNegativeButton("Close", null).show();*/
         Toast.makeText(BlockActivity.this,
                   "Item in position " + position + " clicked",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
    });


pickContact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
.
.
.
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="add" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

detail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:focusable="false">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_gravity="center" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_gravity="center" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip" android:background="#ff7f7f"/>
```

Comment: Is "detail.xml" for the list items?

Comment: In your ListView add `android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"`

Comment: put in item layout android:focusable="false"

Comment: i set them false but noting change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because of your `Button`, add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your list item **root** layout

*detail.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip" android:background="#ff7f7f"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented onClik Listener in CustomAdapter class for Button in detail.xml then please remove it.

Because simultaneously you can not have click on listview's item click and customAdaptor's view click.

Answer (score 0):

For TextViews and Button in your `detail.xml` add this piece of code

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple views in listviews which can be clickable.
Best solution is :

1)Use android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in top-level container layout of list item.

2) Now whichever views in the listview needs to clickable, Use below attribute:

```
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

3)Set click listeners to the views and callback  using interface to fragment or activity on click.